# Print barcode from C# on IIS

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

I have the code working from Visual Studio. But when I put it onto the IIS it doesn't print the barcode, it just gives me the numbers on the label.

I've tried looking up examples but couldn't find anything. This is my first time using barcodes and printing from IIS. Below is the code I have that currently works on Visual Studio but just prints text when I print from my website hosted on IIS.

```
    protected void grdList_RowCommand(object sender, 
    GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        oDL.UpdateCookieExpiry();
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "View")
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                int id = 
                Convert.ToInt32(grdList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);

                string url = "/Stock.aspx?ob_RecordID=" + id;

                Response.Redirect(url, false);
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Print")
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                int id = 
                Convert.ToInt32(grdList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
                try
                {
                    outerboxbc o = new outerboxbc();
                    o = oDL.Get_Outerboxbc(id);

                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

                    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                    this.ob_Barcode.Text = o.barcode.bc_Barcode.ToString();
                    // Set the printer name. 
                    // pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\NS5\hpoffice
                    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "ZDesigner GK420d (Copy 
                    1)";

                    pd.Print();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void pd_PrintPage(object print, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        long de_RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(this.de_RecordID.Value);
        cDelivery d = new cDelivery();
        d = oDL.get_cDelivery(de_RecordID);

        System.Drawing.Image img = 
        System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:AlphaLogo.png");

        int printHeight = 100;
        int printWidth = 250;
        int leftMargin = 0;
        int rightMargin = 0;
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(leftMargin, rightMargin, 
        printWidth, printHeight));

        Font printFont = new Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 24);
        Font printFont1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString("*" + this.ob_Barcode.Text + "*", printFont, 
        br, 10, 130);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(d.de_ProjectNumber, printFont1, br, 110, 
        170);
    }
```

So an example of the barcode.text is "AAC12342313". This prints as a barcode when run using Visual Studio but looks like this on the label "*AAC12342313*" when ran from the website.

Comment: Are you using some library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with printing barcodes, but I don't get how this is supposed to do that.. The only place you're using `ob_Barcode.Text` is in `DrawString`, which unless I'm not mistaken, is just going to literally draw the exact contents of `ob_Barcode.Text`. I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: I put more of my code in for ye. I'm using "System.Drawing;" and "System.Drawing.Printing;"

Comment: Does the IIS server have the font installed? Hopefully this method doesn't need the font to be installed in the browser.

Comment: Yes i have installed the font on the machine hosting the iis.